# how do I overload the << operator to print the contents of an array in c++?

Tags: c++

This is my function, and it is crashing when I run the program. I am trying to print out the contents of a char array. How do I overload this operator to print out the contents of an array without my program crashing?

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, MyString& obj){

  //print out mystring contents

  int i = 0;
  while(i < obj.size)
  {
      out << obj.data[i];
      i++;
  }
}
```

Here are my data members:

```
int size;
int capacity;
char *data;
```

I made the following modifications, but it still crashes:

```
int i = 0;
    while(obj.data[i] != '\0')
    {
        out << obj.data[i];
        i++;
    }

    return out;
```

Comment: `ostream`s are already setup to print character arrays as long as they are null terminated.

Comment: operator<< is a friend of my main class, if that's any help

Comment: you have UB. You forgot the return. Use the compiler warnings.

Comment: @NathanOliver in that case, what should i have inside my function?

Comment: @SarahSepanski Just `out << obj.data;` is all you need to print it if it is null terminated.

Comment: then most likely `obj.data` is not a null terminated string. Use the debugger.

Comment: We need to see more to help you, How is obj.data initialized? This might well be a dangling or null pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return something if you declared your function as such:

```
return out;
```

Without it, you have Undefined Behavior, one possible outcome of which is program crash.

Please, as you are learning set your compiler to treat warnings as errors.

Just a little tip, as NathanOliver said to you, ostreams are already setup to print character arrays as long as they are null terminated, so as long as `obj.data` is a null-terminated string, you can do:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, MyString& obj){

  //print out mystring contents
  if (obj.data != nullptr) // you might need this test, you might not, depending on the internal logic of MyString
    out << obj.data;

  return out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it, but it still crashes on my machine. Perhaps it is some other problem on my end. I will mark your answer as the answer anyway, since I did forget my return statement.

Comment: @SarahSepanski there is no replacement for a debugging session then. I cannot stress enough how important is to be comfortable to do some light debugging whenever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You want to return your `ostream` object:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, MyString& obj) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < obj.size; ++i) {
        out << obj.data[i] << " ";
    }
    return out;
}
```